# importHTML with class declaration

Tags: google-sheets

The code `=ImportHtml(“http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_India“; “table”;4)` is working for me.

I want now to specify HTML element with a certain CSS class. For importXML it works like `=importxml(http://example.com,"//*[@class='teaser']")`  - how should it work for importHTML?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can't target class with ImportHtml, but I have created **ImportXml** in B2 & B3 cells so you can test it here and see if that helps you:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18QIz2fzV0iAI2rdgJqALQx_T9bJjvwyjZIwH-0bLCjI/edit?usp=sharing

```
=ImportXml("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_India", "//*[@id='mw-content-text']/div[6]")
```

and in the B3 cell there is example with class targeting:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_India", "//div[contains(@class, printfooter)]")
```

Comment: the thing is - i want to get not only a content, but the html code too. So if i get the content of a div, i need to get all spans, hrefs etc. which are placed inside of a div. I afraid, importXML doesn't do that - it gets only a clean text:(

Comment: you asked for 'class' targeting so I gave you example, please ask another question for html code capturing